# Calculating overttime wages in python

Tags: python

I am having some problem in my code, it is returning the regular hours and not overtime pay. I am new , and I belive I am not calling the function properly , any help will be appreciated. Thanks All...

```
def computepay(rate, hours):   
    if hours > 40:
        salary = rate * hours
        return salary
    else:
        return (hours-40)*1.5*rate + salary

hours = raw_input("Enter Hours:")
hourly = raw_input("Enter Rate:")
hours = float(hours)
hourly = float(hourly)
p = computepay(hourly,hours)

print p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got the code wrong here. The correct code will be:

```
def compute pay(rate, hours):
    if hours <= 40:
        return rate*hours
    else:
        return (hours-40)*1.5*rate + (40*rate)
```

In your code, in the else condition, you are using salary without defining/declaring it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I got it working now. However I am a bit confused, I called salary = rate* hours , isnt that declaring salary ?

Comment: @RushlanKhan But that else block executes only if the if block does not execute. That is, only if the `hours > 40` condition fails. So Salary will not be declared.